# Windows that follows another existing hwnd window

Tags: c++, windows

I need to create an application with window(B) inside that follows another window(A) in another process that is already in the toolbar. If the user moves the the window A leftwise , the B window follows it to the left. And to copy other actions as well being performed on window A.

Any direction is very welcomed. (i believe i need to implement it with SetWindowsHookex).

Comment: It might be feasible using SplitterWindows : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/969ca366.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a window owned by another process isn't in your control. Hence, you need an IPC mechanism to communicate between your processes, and have the toolbar process move its window when its told to. Assuming you have this IPC mechanism already in place, the procedure would be as follows:

1. Master process starts and creates the Master window
2. Master process associates a callback function with the window (using [RegisterClass()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx#associating_proc))
3. Callback function checks for WM_MOVE messages and forwards the delta (i.e. change in position) to the Slave process (toolbar)
4. Slave process calls MoveWindow() on the slave window with after adding delta to the previous position of the window.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This IPC mechanism is implemented with Windows hooks and SetWindowsHookEx . if we are already talking about it?

Comment: I wouldn't say SetWindowsHookEx is necessarily an IPC mechanism. One approach is to set a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook on the slave process rather than having to do IPC between the processes. That wouldn't work though because the hook will be executed in the context of the process which owns the window (master), and hence MoveWindow on the slave window would fail.

You have a few options for IPC: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, i will indeed check it out.

Comment: If i wanted Window Master to be calculator which means i have no abilitiy to set an IPC from calculator , to my slave window process. How can i set up an IPC to work in this case?